# click() on css Selector not working in Selenium webdriver

Tags: button, selenium, click, css-selectors, webdriver

HTML

```
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="$.reload('results')" value="Search">
```

I don't have an id or name for this .  Hence am writing

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://....");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=Search]")).click();
```

But click() is not happening.

Tried 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".button[value=Search]")).click();

Tried
    value='Search' (single quotes).

these Selectors are working in

```
.button[value=Search] {
padding: 10px;
}
input[value=Search] {
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Looks ok. Are you sure the `driver.get()` loads the correct page ?
Are you using any JS Frameworks ? Maybe you have to wait for some ajax calls to finish.

Comment: Does it find it and just not click it? Throw an exceptions?

Comment: i have luck with driver.get() loading my page.

Comment: @Arran am stuck with that question; am not sure if it is finding my 'Search' button

Comment: If using Firefox, use the IDE with your selector and verifies that the IDE actually sees something.

Comment: single quotes are missing in your code, the **[value=Search]** should be replaced with **[value='Search']**..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would inject piece of js to be confident in resolving this issue:

first of all locate element using DOM (verify in firebug):
[image: locating]

```
public void jsClick(){

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
jsClick();
```

from the retrospective of your element it be like:

```
....
stringBuilder.append("document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();");
....
```

Please, note: `document.getElementsByTagName('input')`  returns you an array of DOM elements. And indexing it properly e.g. document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0], document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6TiC.png), document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2]....
,etc you will be able to locate your element.

Hope this helps you.
Regards.

Comment: This helped to find the element, but click() not happening. driver not executing the click(); is it because i have my onclick event to this input?

Comment: well, try to locate your error step by step. open your page in firefox, open firebug, open console in firebug and simply try to execute following piece of code in console:
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()  and see what happens

Comment: javascript 'click' approach is robust and always works for me. If nothing happens - you should  check carefully that you've found web element properly

Comment: 'Run' on document.getElementsByTagName('button')[5].click(); working absolutely fine.  I just have this public void jsClick(){

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
jsClick();

Comment: nice) so as you can see in this public jsClick you mention improper arg order. change 'document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]' to 'document.getElementsByTagName('button')[5]'. So as I can see it be:
public void jsClick(){ JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); stringBuilder.append("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[5].click();"); js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString()); } jsClick();

Comment: step-by-step debug mode; it executes click() but when i run just this code (Run as Java Application) it is not executing.  I think need a wait time of some seconds before executing the script (may be) or any idea why it works in debug (step over line by line of code) and why not when i run the application.

Comment: add driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4,TimeUnit.SECONDS) between driver.get("http://....");  and performing click operation. it should help

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=\"Search\"]")).click();

It works for me. And make sure that the name is "Search", coz it is case sensitive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that using this CSS-selector (`input[value=Search]`) on your page you have only one result?

Answer (score 0):

single quotes are missing in your code, the **[value=Search]** should be replaced with **[value='Search']**.

first you have to check if the selector u are using will work or not..

If you are using chrome or FF,you can follow these steps,

1. go to the page where button (to be clicked) is present,
2. open web console and type in the following and click enter..

   **$("input[value='Search']")**

or

```
$("input[value='Search'][type='button']")
```

or

```
$("input[value='Search'][type='button'].button")
```

you will get a list of elements which can be accessed using this selector, if that list contains only one element (button that you want to click), then this selector is valid for your use..otherwise u'l have to try some other selector..

If any of the above selector is valid,u'l have to change your code accordingly..

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Search'][type='button'].button")).click();
```