# Selenium WebDriver - Able to locate an object in an IFrame but Click() is not accurate

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The application under test spawns an IFrame for a functionality. I am able to locate the elements perfectly on the IFrame by using any of the following locator strategies, XPATH, CSS or LinkText. However, when I perform a `Click()`, the code clicks on a different location. For example, the screen has a multiple choice question with 4 answers and the script is supposed to click on the 3rd option, but it ends up clicking on the 1st. The problem is much more severe in case of a button where it is not able to click on the button at all. The `Click()` event does not throw any error though. I have tried using the `Action()` interface but with no luck. The `Action.Perform()` throws an error that the screen element is outside the HTML. Can anybody help?

I am using the Selenium WebDriver (.NET) Version 2.31 and Firefox 19.0.2 with .NET framework 4.0.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(2);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
IWebElement Answer1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='question-reload']/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a"));
Answer1.Click();
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Find the embassy")).Click();
IWebElement Next = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='next']/b/i"));
int X = Next.Location.X;
int Y = Next.Location.Y;
Next.Click();

    for (int i = 0; i < 59; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);        
        IWebElement newNext = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='next']/b/i"));
        newNext.Click();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the element id, xpath or css are not changing dynamically? can you check that once and let us know?

Comment: @HemChe: The element does not have an ID. But the other locator values are not changing dynamically for sure.

Comment: Just an update. The script is able to click on the Next button when executed in Debug mode. But fails when executed fully. Tried with creating intelligent wait for element before the Click() event but no luck.

Comment: One recommendation I have is to download Selenium IDE (plugin for FireFox).  Click on the element.  In the `Target` field, selenium will have several options for targets.  You can change it to `css, xpath:idRelative, or xpath:position`.  That way you can try different options and also test that your xpath string is correct.

Comment: We will need a copy of the HTML to replicate the problem too. In your `for` loop, you are not using the counter variable (`i`) at all, BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I was able to solve the issue by injecting JavaScript for clicking on the Next button. Here goes the code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);               
IJavaScriptExecutor exec = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
StringBuilder locator = new StringBuilder();
locator.Append("document.getElementById('next').click();");
exec.ExecuteScript(locator.ToString());
```

Thanks a lot to [this piece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040719/click-on-css-selector-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver) and all of you who pitched in!!