# Click on hyperlink using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium

I am having a problem while trying to click on a hyperlink using Selenium Webdriver. I tried using CssSelector as well as XPath and nothing seem to work. All I am trying to do is Click on the Google text.

```
    <div class="hello">
    <div class="test">
    <table class="first first-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="second-table">
    <a id="dummyID" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
   </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>`
```

I tried driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='dummyID']")).Click(); I also tried using href to find the link...pretty much everything. All the time I am getting "unable to locate element" exception. Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Is the Link contained within a frame or iframe?

Comment: @Richard That's a good question..

Comment: Looking at the HTML using Firebug, I don't see any frame/iframe.

Comment: I think at this point, we're going to need to see some more html, and possibly your code from initializing the driver to where you attempt to click the link.

Comment: Try this if it helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040719/click-on-css-selector-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I wonder if this element is being loaded after performing some action?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Google")).Click();
```

Look to see if the element is within a frame or iframe.  If it is, you'll need to use:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frameID");
```

Comment: Then what's the problem here `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='dummyID']")).Click()` ?

Comment: It doesn't have frame..at least the pagesource doesn't show any frame.

Comment: @user1493537 afaik, frames may be not present in page source. In your Firebug, on the left side of locator input there's a drop down. What does it show?

Comment: Yes, I checked it and there are no frames.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Google")).Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find by id:

```
driver.FindElement(By.id("dummyID")).Click();
```

Or you can use this xpath in your scenario:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id='dummyID']")).Click();
```

You can directly find the element by id, it is an easy and efficient approach.
I hope you will get your desired click on it with any of these code fragments, both should work the same. Surely it will work.

Answer (score 0):

None of the proposed solutions will work every time. Hyperlinks cannot be treated like other clickable web elements such as buttons.  A hyperlink is disabled by removing the `href` attribute from the anchor tag. For other components, the web driver can interrogate the found web element to see if is enabled or clickable.  Consider the following scenario:

```
<a id="dummyID" target="_blank">Google</a>

WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='Google']")));
element.click();
```

Because the `ExpectedConditions` class cannot make a determination of the "clickability" of the link like it can do with an input element (such as button), it will not throw a `TimeoutException` and will allow your test to click a dead (disabled) link. Therefore, for hyperlinks exclusively, you must either search for an anchor tag with an `href` attribute in it, or test the consequence of the click (i.e. a change in URL).

Another thing you should try to avoid is the use of `//*` to locate web elements. You can run into situations where more than one element will be found and you'll end up interacting with the incorrect one.

Lastly, the problem with `driver.FindElement(...)` is that you can run into issues with `NoSuchElement` exceptions if the page has not loaded fully (unless you set an implicit wait of some kind). The preferred way to wait for an element to interact with, it by using explicit waits, like the Java example I provided above. Since I do not know what issue you ran into, I have to assume this could be your issue. If this is not the issue, perhaps the element is inside an `iframe` in which case, you will need to tell the web driver to switch to the correct `iframe` prior to interacting with the element.