# How to find href through class name and click with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, href

I'm using Selenium with python to make a spider.

A part of the web page is like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.html" target="_blank" class="_j_search_link">text - <span class="sr-keyword">name</span> text</a>
```

I need to find the href and click.

I've tried as below:

```
target = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_j_search_link')
target.click()
```

target is not `None` but it doesn't seem that it could be clicked because after `target.click()`, nothing happened.

Also, I've read this question: [Click on hyperlink using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060806/click-on-hyperlink-using-selenium-webdriver)

But it can't help me because in my case, there is a `<span class>`, not just a simple text `Google`.

Comment: Did click work on other elements?

Comment: @HarshithThota  Well, it works on buttons.

Comment: And you said target is not none. What is it?

Comment: @HarshithThota  Because I've printed it: `print(target)`. It shows: `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="803a32f3fd3547a1a07b1e85b0ce0a83", element="0.7253881462980114-1")>`.

Comment: @HarshithThota   hmm.... It seems there exists many `_j_search_link`. Wait a sec...

Comment: Check if this locator match other elements as well.

Comment: Tell me about this link. Does the text value change? Where you mentioned "text -".

Comment: @HarshithThota  Here is the web page: http://www.mafengwo.cn/search/s.php?q=%E5%A5%91%E8%BF%AA%E9%BE%99%E5%AF%BA&seid=339A1E5A-E79C-4F55-9E52-F2990574CB08

Comment: @HarshithThota  I just want to click the first link on the top, which is `景点 - 契迪龙寺 Wat Chedi Luang`.

Comment: You can try with css selector #_j_search_result_left h3>._j_search_linka

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click on hyperlink using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060806/click-on-hyperlink-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("Wat Chedi Luang").click()
```

Comment: Once again mobile lag gets in the way :/

Answer (score 2):

You can look for an element with class `_j_search_link` that contains text `Wat Chedi Luang`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="_j_search_link" and contains(., "Wat Chedi Luang")]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't find right element. Use CSS or Xpath to target this element then click it, like:

```
//a[@class='_j_search_link']
```

or

```
//a[@class='_j_search_link']/span[@class='sr-keyword']
```